# Order by clause inside sub query causing error

Tags: sql, sql-server

Why is this query not working?

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT
        p.FirstName as name,
        DATEDIFF(YYYY,p.dob,GETDATE()) AS age
    FROM Person.Person p 
    WHERE p.dob is not null
    ORDER BY age
) a
```

throws the following error in SQL Server.

> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived
>   tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET
>   or FOR XML is also specified.

When I execute only the inner sub query it woks perfectly.

Comment: You should order outer query (assuming u need it at all)

Comment: The error message tell you exactly why.

Comment: Why even have the outer query?

Comment: What is the purpose of the outer query?

Comment: I want to group the result by age group and output the count for each age group

Comment: Did you *try* it without the `ORDER BY` clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As previously stated, order by is not allowing in a subquery.

The reason is that a subquery by definition is called by another query.  It is that outer query that determines the order of results.  Orderying an intermediate result set has no effect on the order of the final result.  Thus sql server dissallows you from adding an order by to a subquery to prevent you even thinking that it has an effect in your query.  If it allowed the order by, Microsoft would get a ton of bug reports: order by is not working, when it is working perfectly, it is just not applied to the final result set.

Edit in response to question about if the order by could improve join performance.

SQL Server will determine the best way to join two result sets.  In your case, especially if the id is a clustered key, it will likely select the subquery in id order and then run a join based on that order (merge join).  But it doesn't have to.  If your  where clause restricts the rows returned enough, it could decide it would be faster do something else like a nested loop join.  You are trying to help the optimizer with the order by.  Likely it will do the order by internally and you can check the execution plan to see.  However, it has the option to do a different join it thinks that will be quicker.

Let sql server optimize itself.  Sql is language that describes what you want, not how to get it.  I want these columns from these tables in this order.  Let sql server decide if an intermediate order by would allow it to run quicker.  Don't try to force it to run a certain way.  It knows far more about its capabilities and your data than either of us.

Comment: just to expand the scope here, if I want to use the "subquery" as a resultset which can be joined with a different set, shouldnt it be allowed to order by a key so that the join works efficiently?

Comment: I would like to do something like this
`select s.ID, s.NAME, s.STATE_NAME
from Test_trigger.dbo.UScounties s
left join
(select i.id, i.STATE_FIPS from Test_trigger.dbo.UScounties i where i.STATE_FIPS = 53 order by i.ID) as a
on s.ID = a.ID`

Answer (score 2):

Your sub query can not have an order by as the error states.  Try this instead

```
select * from
(
select 
    p.FirstName as name,
    DATEDIFF(YYYY,p.dob,GETDATE()) AS age
from Person.Person p 
where p.dob is not null

) a
ORDER BY a.age
```

Comment: I known taking out the order by clause outside solves the issue, but it would be nice is someone can state some concrete reason for restricting it.

Comment: Well, for starters, ordering an inner query won't necessarily accomplish anything. The order of the final result is determined by the outer query. Ordering an inner query won't reliably give you an ordered final result, because it depends on how the inner query is then used by the outer query.

Comment: Agreed, SQL Server is trying to prevent you from writing a poor performing query.  Any join or union will throw off the sorting so why do it at all.

Answer (score 1):

```
select a.name,a.age from
(
select 
    p.FirstName as name,
    DATEDIFF(YYYY,p.dob,GETDATE()) AS age
from Person.Person p 
where p.dob is not null

) a
ORDER BY a.age
```

Answer (score 0):

Ordering an inner query doesn’t make sense from SQL Server implementation of RA point of view. SQL Server doesn’t guarantee nor assume any order when returning or retrieving rows; a talbe  is just an unordered Relation that can be presented in a specific order using the order by clause. 
Since RA is an algebraic closure, the result of an expression is also a Relation, which means that the result of a subquery is also a Relation where the order of the returned rows is not guaranteed. Therefore order by in a subquery would have the same effect on the outer query as the order of rows in a physical table have on a select statement, i.e. no effect whatsoever.